# Equivalent of memcpy in opencl

Tags: opencl

I'm new to opencL and this question might look silly.

I have a kernel which takes two structures A and C. I want to copy contents of structure A to structure C.

Structure looks like below:

```
struct Block {

  bool used;
  int size;
  intptr_t data[1];

};


__kernel void function(__global struct Block *A, __global struct Block *C) {
//Do something on A
//COPY A to C by memcpy alternative
}
```

Is there any function like memcpy which I can use inside kernel?. I'm using opencl in integrated GPU with zero copy.

Or Do I have to copy block by block to structure C?.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this inside a kernel? You can use the GPU's DMA engine for copies using [`clEnqueueCopyBuffer()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueCopyBuffer.html).

Comment: If there's a good reason to do this inside a kernel, you may also want to experiment with using `async_work_group_copy()` and/or `async_work_group_strided_copy()` to copy your data in 2 stages via `global` -> `local` -> `global` memory which could be more efficient than copying struct-by-struct. I'm not aware of a direct `global` -> `global` `memcpy()` like function for use in kernels.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can simply assign the structures:

```
__kernel void function(__global struct Block *A, __global struct Block *C) {
  //Do something on A
  *C = *A;
}
```

It's same as in plain C, yet many programmers don't know they can assign structures and resort to `memcpy`.